# delete object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object:

```
const data = { theValues: [ 
    {key1: "valueOne",
     key2: "someValue"}, 
    {key1:  "valueTwo",
     key2: "moreValue"}]};
```

If i use the following:

```
data.theValues = data.theValues.filter(obj => obj.key1 != 'valueOne');
```

I get this  as result:

```
 const data = { theValues: [ 
    {key1:  "valueTwo",
     key2: "moreValue"}]};
```

Ok and thats what I wanted too. But if I have the this object:

```
 const data = { theValues: [ 
     {key1:  ["valueOne", "valueTwo"],
      key2: "otherValue"},    
     {key1:  ["valueThree","valueFour"],
      key2: "noValue"}]};
```

And I use the same thing:

```
data.theValues = data.theValues.filter(obj => obj.key1 != 'valueOne');
```

Nothing happens. Why is that and how can I delete the object with the value 'valueOne'?

Comment: It's because in the first example `key1` is a `string` property, whilst in the second example `key1` is an `array` property. You should also [consider using `!==` instead of `!=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons), if you don't have a specific use case for the `!=` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of `key` is an array, you can't compare it to a string - `obj.key1 != 'valueOne'` is always `true`. Check the array doesn't include the term (`valueOne`) using `Array.includes()`:

```js
const data = {"theValues":[{"key1":["valueOne","valueTwo"],"key2":"otherValue"},{"key1":["valueThree","valueFour"],"key2":"noValue"}]};

const result = data.theValues.filter(obj => !obj.key1.includes('valueOne'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are comparing array with string. Here, `key1` is an array and `valueOne` is string. You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. Filter array where `key1` does not contain `valueOne`.

> Some method returns true if at least one element in the array passes the test.

```js
const data = {
  theValues: [
    { key1: ['valueOne', 'valueTwo'], key2: 'otherValue' },
    { key1: ['valueThree', 'valueFour'], key2: 'noValue' },
  ],
};
const ret = data.theValues.filter((x) => !x.key1.some((y) => y === 'valueOne'));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `key1` is array, not key of object. So you can use [indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to get desired result:

```
const result = data.theValues.filter(obj => obj.key1.indexOf('valueOne'));
```

An example:

```js
const data = { "theValues":
    [
          { "key1": ["valueOne", "valueTwo"], "key2": "otherValue" }
        , { "key1": ["valueThree", "valueFour"], "key2": "noValue" }
    ]
};



const result = data.theValues.filter(obj => obj.key1.indexOf('valueOne'));

console.log(result);
```